# Rendered mp3 file is much larger than original

Tags: vegas-pro, compression

In Sony Vegas Pro 10 I've placed an `.mp3` file (about **3MB** file size), then I've cut it slightly at the end to **shorten the length**. I've tried to encode it with following settings:

```
File - Render As  
Save As Type: MP3 Audio  
Template: Default Template  
Description: Audio: 256 Kbps, 44,100 Hz, 16 Bit, Stereo, MP3
```

The encoded file is about **6MB** and it seems that the resulting file is the same quality as original.

How can I render `.mp3` without getting a larger file size than the original?

Comment: OK, the output is 256kbps / 44.1K. But what are the sample rate and bit rate for the original file?

Comment: @JimMack, how can I check this data, pls?

Comment: Use [Mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo). I don't really know Vegas, but it should have some sort of metadata display as well ...

Comment: My guess would be that the original file was not recorded at 256kbps, but something lower like 192 or maybe even 128.

Answer (score 1):

The settings say Stereo. The doubling of file size might indicate that the original file was mono.